# Date picker in WPF xaml /C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012

HI would like to ask on how i can apply this example from this site?.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308514.aspx

Tried recreating the code locally but always some part are not accepted specially in the datepicker:

The Visual Studio wont accept DayFormat, MonthFormat,YearFormat

```
<DatePicker DayFormat="{}{day.integer}" MonthFormat="{}{month.integer}" YearFormat="{}{year.abbreviated}"/>
```

The VS show error the the DayFormat and the other two is no accesible or not recognize
Do i have to add reference or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is only available in Visual Studio 2013 and on Windows 8.1 or Windows Phone 8.1  You're using Visual Studio 2012 (not sure what operating system you're using, since you haven't mentioned it).

Comment: I am using windows 8.1

Comment: @Jigen Well, you're still using VS 2012 and it's not compatible with it.